# Does plurality mean that it must have more than 1 camera?

Tags: terminology

The patent says:

> using each of the plurality of digital cameras

Does that mean that it only covers systems that have 2 or more cameras? Or would it cover a system with only 1 camera.

Comment: Hi Frank, it looks like you deleted the tag which might help us determine what patent you are asking about. Can you please include a patent or publication number?

Answer (score 3):

Absent some reason from departing from the normal meaning, this language would seem to define something having 2 or more cameras, all of which must be being used.

Comment: Departing from normal meaning could be, e.g., a reference to a plurality of digital cameras in the specification that defines the term as including the singular (notwithstanding, it would be an up-hill battle for the patentee to argue against the plain English interpretation) - in nearly all cases the wording means at least 2.

Answer (score 0):

All the other stuff out there, which has been Officially introduced to the public in The U.S. Patent Office, "the plurality". In terms of patents "the plurality" meeting the standards by The U.S. Patent Office. However, in this event, "each of" qualified use of "the plurality". Therefore, all the stuff with more than one camera out there formally introduced to the public in this arena. Use of "the plurality", I take, here as meaning all previously known things practicing the art. Hence, meaning more than one.